# How to set custom date format when exporting excel using xml and datagridview in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel, date, datagridview

I am having a hardtime setting the custom format for exporting excel.
The custom date format that want for the excel is yyyy-mm-dd.
I already set the date format in the datagridview but it doesn't affect or work in the excel.

```
 Private Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal DGV As DataGridView)

        Dim fs As New StreamWriter(filePathAndNameHome, False)

        With fs
            .WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0""?>")
            .WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>")
            .WriteLine("<Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"">")
            '...
            .WriteLine("    </Styles>")

            If DGV.Name = "Report" Then
                .WriteLine("    <Worksheet ss:Name=""Report"">") 'SET NAMA SHEET
                .WriteLine("        <Table>")
                'Columns
                '...
            End If

            'AUTO SET HEADER
            .WriteLine("            <Row ss:StyleID=""ksg"">")
            For i As Integer = 0 To DGV.Columns.Count - 1 'SET HEADER
                Application.DoEvents()
                .WriteLine("            <Cell ss:StyleID=""hdr"">")
                .WriteLine("                <Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</Data>", DGV.Columns.Item(i).HeaderText)
                .WriteLine("            </Cell>")
            Next
            'The row
            .WriteLine("            </Row>")
            For intRow As Integer = 0 To DGV.RowCount - 1
                Application.DoEvents()
                .WriteLine("        <Row ss:StyleID=""ksg"" ss:utoFitHeight =""0"">")

                For intCol As Integer = 0 To DGV.Columns.Count - 1
                    Application.DoEvents()
                    .WriteLine("        <Cell ss:StyleID=""isi"">")
                    .WriteLine("            <Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</Data>", DGV.Item(intCol, intRow).Value) 'How to change its date format
                    .WriteLine("        </Cell>")
                Next
                .WriteLine("        </Row>")
            Next
            .WriteLine("        </Table>")
            .WriteLine("    </Worksheet>")
            .WriteLine("</Workbook>")
            .Close()
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with [tag:c#]?

Comment: @DavidG cast a wide net...

Comment: @Plutonix Should have tagged PHP or Javascript then!

Comment: Setting the format in the DGV just changes how it is displayed (dates cannot have a format).  You probably want to export it as `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel XML, how can I get Excel to display my DateTime field in yyyy-MM-dd format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057875/excel-xml-how-can-i-get-excel-to-display-my-datetime-field-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Comment: I tagged this with C# because it was suggested by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, if you change the custom format of cell `A1` to `yyyy-mm-dd`, and then type `?[a1].value(11)` in the VBA Immediate window, you get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy\-mm\-dd"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1">
   <Column ss:Width="53.25"/>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
     <Data ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T00:00:00.000</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

so change the `ss:Type` to `DateTime` and add the number format to the isi style definition

```
  <Style ss:ID="isi">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy\-mm\-dd"/>
  </Style>
```

Comment: How to apply it in for loop?

Comment: @GuideMe something like `.WriteLine("            <Data ss:Type=""DateTime"">{0}</Data>", DGV.Item(intCol, intRow).Value) `

Comment: I cannot open the exported excel file. I has unknown error.

Comment: I've got an error in the excel after I added the DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set custom format in excel, first, we need to determine the column number where the date is located or inserted.

Once you have determine the column number, you just have to add condition like this:

```
 For intCol As Integer = 0 To DGV.Columns.Count - 1
         Application.DoEvents()
         .WriteLine("        <Cell ss:StyleID=""isi"">")
            If intCol = 7 Or intCol = 12 Or intCol = 14 Or intCol = 15 Then 'if column 7 or ... has date set custom format
               .WriteLine("            <Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</Data>", Format(DGV.Item(intCol, intRow).Value, "yyyy-MM-dd").ToString())
            Else
               .WriteLine("            <Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</Data>", DGV.Item(intCol, intRow).Value)
            End If
         .WriteLine("        </Cell>")
     Next
```